# Memory Leak when freeing a char array

Tags: c++, memory

I have malloc a char array and initialize it:

```
int i;
int length = 100;
char *arr = (char *) malloc (length * sizeof(char));
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

then I set the middle char to '\0':

```
arr[50] = '\0';
```

In this case, arr only has invalid length 50, not 100
then I use free:

```
free(arr);
```

can this cause memory leak? ie the operating system will record the malloc length or just use strlen to judge the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. the contents of the memory has no impact on how `free()` works.

`free()` doesn't know you were using this as a null terminated char string. It would never use `strlen()` on a chunk of memory.

Try a tool like valgrind to check your code for leaks.

Answer (score 2):

`free` knows the size of the allocated memory block. Well, how does it know the size? This is implementation dependent, but often times it stores the size right before the start of the actual memory block it allocates. For example, on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=10ae4dfd1eaff193b4d6869a7b37d610-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51), the following program prints `113` (113 means it is allocating more memory than we actually ask for).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 char *arr = (char *) malloc (100 * sizeof(char));
 std::cout << *((std::size_t*)arr - 1) << std::endl;
}
```

This is quite out of date, but reading [A Memory Allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) might be a good idea. It will give you an idea of what is going on better (just keep in mind that there might be differences with the actual implementation).

Comment: "there might be differences with the actual implementation" - true. Specially since your example officially causes an undefined behavior.