# Possible to manually leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I was wondering what happens if I put '\0' in the middle of "malloc"ed memory.

I came upon this question. [Memory Leak when freeing a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417076/memory-leak-when-freeing-a-char-array)

In the Jesse Good's answer, it says this line will print out the size of the "malloc"ed memory.

```
std::cout << *((std::size_t*)arr - 1) << std::endl;
```

Does that mean if I modify the value of *((std::size_t*)arr - 1), the size of memory that's going to be freed when I call "free" will be different and cause memory leak if the modified value is smaller than the original value?

Comment: "**might print out**" and "**may cause memory leak**". This is implementation-dependent behaviour, read your standard library's implementation of malloc to learn how it frees memory. Without knowing which one you use, any answer would be speculation.

Comment: No. The answer is [in the thread you refer to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17417163/2633423). In short: `free` knows the size of the memory block it is going to free, assuming you pass it a pointer to a block obtained from `malloc` (otherwise you have undefined behavior).

Comment: You're using undocumented feature, and by doing so you trigger undefined behavior. Your program could work, could crash, or it could awaken Cthulhu. Nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: i might wrong but i think that using malloc/realloc/free in c++ is bad practice ... and when it comes to strings i would suggest to use `std::string` for high level usage. if you want a char array use `std::vector<char>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer you are referring to is misleading. Read the accepted answer.

It is true that, if your system uses certain memory allocators, it is possible to read the `size_t` value preceding a memory block to determine the size of that block. However:

- Not all memory allocators work this way. Some will store other values in that location, such as pointers to other memory blocks, and some don't use it for anything that will be meaningful to you at all.
- The results of reading memory outside an allocated block are **undefined**. In some circumstances, an address preceding the allocated block may be outside your process's memory space, and accessing it will cause a segfault.
- Modifying that value will most likely corrupt the state of your memory allocator and cause your program to behave incorrectly and/or crash when it allocates or frees memory.

Do not read or write memory outside of allocated regions.